# PHP PDO code to start for loop from user defined value

Tags: php, pdo

I need to start my for loop from user defined no.

For example, if I enter start:

```
250, book_no  = 2
```

it generates data like:

```
251
251
252
252
```

What to change in my `for` loop to work like this?

I tried below code but this does not insert any values and also does not shows error.

```
 $book_no = $_POST['book_no'];
    for($row1=250;$row1<=$book_no;$row1++)
    {
    $insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO scheme_master (book_no) VALUES (:book_no)",  array(':book_no'=>$row1));
    }
```

Comment: Get a good IDE (e.g. PHPstorm community edition, NetBeans, etc). Learn how to use the debugger. Set breakpoints in your code & run to them, when you hit them, examine variables. You will soon figure it out and won't have to ask here. There, now you have learned how to fish ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 for($row1=$min;$row1<=$max;$row1++)
     {
         for($row=1;$row<=$book_no;$row++)
            {
                $insertrow = $database->insertRow(
                    "INSERT INTO scheme_master
                         (book_no,receipt_no,created) VALUES (:book_no)", 
                    array(':book_no'=>$row1)
                );
            }
        }
```

Comment: Without any explanation, people may wonder what this is for. Would you edit in, before the code, an introduction? If this is the solution to the problem, how does it solve it?